# Help required for SharePoint Installation

Tags: sharepoint-server

[image]

Dear All,Kindly help to solve this error

Comment: We need more to help you! Have you checked the log file linked in the window? What errors did it log?

Comment: Did you run prerequisites installer?

Comment: You should install WCF Services Tools using prerequisites installer Check the details at [SharePoint 2016: Failed to create the configuration database. An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown](https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/05/21/sharepoint-2016-failed-to-create-the-configuration-database-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup user administrator account**

This account is used to set up each server in your farm by running the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, the initial Farm Configuration Wizard, and Windows PowerShell.

The setup user administrator account is used for farm administration, and you can use Central Administration to manage it. Some configuration options, for example, configuration of the SharePoint Server 2016 Search query server, require local administration permissions.

The setup user administrator account requires the following permissions:

- It must have domain user account permissions.
- It must be a member of the local administrators group on each server in the SharePoint farm.
- This account must have access to the SharePoint databases.
- If you use any Windows PowerShell operations that affect a database,
  the setup user administrator account must be a member of the **db_owner**
  role.
- This account must be assigned to the **securityadmin** and **dbcreator** SQL
  Server security roles during setup and configuration.

Please check if your account used to create is having DB Owner Access.

**You can check and provide DB Admin access if not provided earlier. Delete those config DB created earlier and try installing SharePoint once again.**

This should help resolve the issue.

References :[Account and Permissions Required](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863(v=office.16).aspx)